# Angular, DragnDrop Issue, localstorage

Tags: angular, rxjs, drag-and-drop, local-storage, observable

features: Feature[] = [];

with this code, i can make this array items drag and drop and after it save in storage

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.features , event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  window.localStorage.setItem('features', JSON.stringify(this.features));
}
```

with this, i subscribing data, everything ok...
in this case everything works fine, even then i add new item

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.featuresService.getFeatures();
  this.featuresSub = this.featuresService.getFeatureUpdateListener()
  .subscribe((featureData: {features: Feature[]}) => {
   this.features = featureData.features
   this.isLoading = false;
```

but if i replace this line this.features =featuresData.features to this
i will see only saved localstorage data

```
   let retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("features") || '{}';
   let newFeaturesArr = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
   this.features = newFeaturesArr

  })
  .....
```

Is any idea how mix this both logic that if i refresh page see localstorage sorted items and + if i add new item show it in last immediately

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be more to your question than is clear but from what you've said you can either create both localStorage data and newFeatures as objects and merge them:

```js
this.features = Object.assign(retrievedData, newFeatures);
```

or create both as arrays and merge them:

```js
this.features = retrievedData.concat(newFeatures)
```